# Specify slugify mode

Tags: ruby, jekyll, slug

I am using slugify in my HTML template like this

```
{{ category | slugify }}
```

But how can I specify non-default mode for the slugify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ "The cönfig.yml file" | slugify: 'latin' }}
```

See `slugify` filter in the [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/).